# Iterate over column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `employee` object that I'd like to just show a list of the keys and the associated values for in the `show.html.erb` file. Here's what I have currently, but how can this be done with a `for` loop?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td><%= @employee.name %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email</td>
  <td><%= @employee.email %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Job Code</td>
  <td><%= @employee.job_code %></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

Comment: Have you used .each before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @employee.attributes.each do |key, value| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= key.gsub('_', ' ').titleize %></td>
    <td><%= value %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```